# If Player ID's Match on separate worksheets, Copy data from different cell in same row

Tags: excel-formula

All players are assigned player ID's on two different worksheets.

On worksheet 1 I have row of 100 Player IDs in Column C. 
On Worksheet 2 I have the Player ID in Column C & Player Score in Column K

On worksheet 1 I would like to copy into Column E, the score if the player ID's match.

Example  Worksheet 1

Column C               Column D        Column E

Player ID              Name           IF C = Any ID in Column "C" on Worksheet 2 Copy "K" from that row

Example  Worksheet 2

Column C               Column K

Player ID              Player Score

Comment: give us a demo worksheet please

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLOOKUP function if each player ID only has 1 score.

so in cell E1 of worksheet 1, you put:

```
=VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!C1, 'Sheet2'!$C1:$K100, 9, FALSE)
```

Then you drag this formula down to populate the rest of the column E.